# flask render_template javascript loading order

Tags: javascript, flask

I am curious about the loading order of javascript when using the render_template function in flask.

what I understand is load js file in head part is first
and the scripts will be loaded line by line in body partition .

but when I use the codes as below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ"
          crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}">

    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='scripts.js') }}" type="module"></script>

    <title>test web page</title>
</head>
<body>

<script>console.log('start base 1html')</script>
<!-- include navbar -->
{% include "navbar.html" %}
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- include sidebar -->
        <div class="col-md-2 bg-c">
            {% include "sidebar.html" %}
        </div>

        <!-- content Start -->
        <div class="col-md-10">


            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>console.log('start base2 html')</script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script_body.js') }}" type="module"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

I put console.log for every imported file

and I can found result in my browser as attatched photo .

I cannot understand why the script.js file does not imported at first  ???
is there any order rule for import ?
[image]

Comment: It caused by type parameter.
```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='scripts.js') }}" type="module"></script>
```

Comment: Have you tried in different browsers with the same result? Afaik when scripts are added dynamically different browsers assign different priorities to them